# How can I add Attributes to a PHP SoapVar Object?

Tags: php, soap

How can I add Attributes to a PHP SoapVar Object? (PHP5, SoapClient, SoapVar)

I have a SOAP Client Request situation where I have repeating sections ("answers"), each with a question and choice. It's all part of a Quiz scoring process. Based on what I have seen with the PHP5 SOAP Client, the array approach is not viable since the "answer" tags are repeated. Correct me if you know how to write this with an array structure.

So, I used SoapVar objects to define the complex object structure. All went fairly well, until I noticed I needed Attributes in one of the outside tags; identityRequest.

```
<ns1:invokeIdentityService>
<ns1:identityRequest>
<ns1:scoreRequest>
<ns1:quizId>6982971</ns1:quizId>
<ns1:answer>
<ns1:questionId>25867508</ns1:questionId>
<ns1:choiceId>128423504</ns1:choiceId>
</ns1:answer>
<ns1:answer>
<ns1:questionId>25867509</ns1:questionId>
<ns1:choiceId>128423507</ns1:choiceId>
</ns1:answer>
<ns1:answer>
<ns1:questionId>25867510</ns1:questionId>
<ns1:choiceId>128423514</ns1:choiceId>
</ns1:answer>
</ns1:scoreRequest>
</ns1:identityRequest>
```

I've seen how to add attributes using an array structure, but how can it be done with a complex object? I can't this answer anywhere in the PHP book or online.

I need to add 4 attributes (customerReference, locale, productAlias, and transactionId) to the identityRequest object that will show up in the SOAP body.

```
$answers = array();
// Start array with Quiz ID: quizId and questionId/choiceId are at the same level.
$answers[] = new SoapVar($quiz_id, XSD_STRING, null, null, 'quizId', $this->is);

foreach ($input as $name=>$value) {
    if (preg_match('/^question([0-9]*)$/i', $name, $parts)) {
        // Build questionId/choiceId
        $answer = array();
        $answer[] = new SoapVar($parts[1], XSD_STRING, null, null, 'questionId', $this->is);
        $answer[] = new SoapVar($value , XSD_STRING, null, null, 'choiceId', $this->is);
        // Build answer
        $answers[] = new SoapVar((array)$answer, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'answer', $this->is);
    }
}

// Build scoreRequest from $answers (includes quizId)
$scoreRequest = new SoapVar((array)$answers, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'scoreRequest', $this->is);

// Wrap with identityRequest
$identityRequest = new SoapVar(array('scoreRequest' => $scoreRequest), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'identityRequest', $this->is);

$params = array(
    'identityRequest' => $identityRequest,
    'customerReference' => 'Company12345',
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'productAlias' => 'Alias6789',
    'transactionID' => 'transId1234',
);
$request = new SoapVar($params, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'request', $this->is);
```

How can I add those 4 attributes into the SoapVar? As you can see from above, I've tried a mix of object/array with $params, but that doesn't seem to work. I just end up with several additional XML tags/values.

I'm looking for something like:

```
<ns1:invokeIdentityService ns1:customerReference="Company12345" ns1:locale="en_US" ns1:productAlias="Alias6789" ns1:transactionID="transId1234">
```

I hope someone can provide some help. I'm exhausted. I've struggled with PHP5 SOAP, as have many others it seems. I always seems like it's harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Why don't you want to use array? Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php#83409 for creating complex object.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I can't use an array with repeating elements, such as "answer". Or is there a way of repeating elements - array style?

Comment: I did successfully use a stdClass() object to add the attributes. The request was then a combination of SoapVar Objects and stdClass Objects. Seems to work. BTW, trying to mix objects and arrays into the soap request doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone wanted a bit more detail on the stdClass() object, so here it is. I don't claim that this is a good way to code this problem. There are bound to be better ways.

```
    // Build scoreRequest from $answers (includes quizId)
    $scoreRequest = new SoapVar((array)$answers, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'scoreRequest', $this->is);

    // SoapVar not used pass this point; see below.
    //$identityRequest = new SoapVar(array('scoreRequest' => $scoreRequest), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'identityRequest');

    // scoreQuizRequest uses a mixture of SoapVar Objects and stdClass Objects.
    // stdClass Object is used to allow us to define the attributes for 
    // identityRequest, such as productAlias & transactionID.
    // Note: $scoreRequest is a SoapVar Object.
    $request = new stdClass();
    $request->identityRequest = new stdClass();
    $request->identityRequest->scoreRequest = $scoreRequest;

    $request->identityRequest->customerReference = $this->customerReference;
    $request->identityRequest->locale = $this->locale;
    $request->identityRequest->productAlias = $this->productAlias;
    $request->identityRequest->transactionID = $this->transactionId;
```