# PHP SOAP complex types

Tags: php, soap

I have a working XML request body, which I'm trying to send via PHP to a SOAP server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="urn:servicewsdl" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <mns:getQuote xmlns:mns="urn:getquoteswsdl" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <authorisation xsi:type="tns:Authorisation">
        <username xsi:type="xsd:string">****</username>
        <password xsi:type="xsd:string">****</password>
    </authorisation>
    <symbol xsi:type="xsd:string">****</symbol>
    </mns:getQuote>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I tried passing the params in an array like so:

```
$result = $client->getQuote(array('username' => '****', 'password' => '****'), array('symbol' => '****'));
```

but it returns me an error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'username' property
```

Comment: I updated my answer to include an object method rather than array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably need to put the username/password array inside authorisation like:

```
$result = $client->getQuote(array('authorisation'=>array('username' => '****', 'password' => '****')), array('symbol' => '****'));
```

or, maybe you should send it an object instead:

```
$params = new stdClass();
$params->authorisation = new stdClass();
$params->authorisation->username = '****';
$params->authorisation->password = '****';
$params->symbol = '****';
$result = $client->getQuote($params);
```

EDIT: From the comments, in the end, getQuote was accessed via PHP in this method:

```
$auth = new stdClass();
$auth->username = '****';
$auth->password = '****';
$symbol = '****';
$result = $client->getQuote($auth, $symbol);
```

Comment: When I fire the request through PHP i get the following error: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'username' property. This only happens in PHP, when I carry out the query with the given XML or using an online tool this error isnt shown. Any ideas?

Comment: @twigg Hmm, have you tried just $params->username and the same for password? Instead of nesting inside authorisation?

Comment: I removed that and it passed the auth part but is now saying invalid symbol, I guess I need to pass the symbol in another way? (yes the symbol I'm passing is defiantly correct)

Comment: Sorry, on phone so formatting is horrible. Maybe symbol needs sent as a second object?  $client->getQuote($auth_object,$symbol_object);

Comment: Hi bob, no problem I tried two objects but get 'Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string' I'm guessing you can't pass an object as the second param?

Comment: Hi bob, oh dear god.... the symbol just needed a string passing in as the second param  $client->getQuote($params, '****'); I got there in the end with your guidance so thank you

Comment: Glad you got there in the end!

Answer (score 1):

I had a heck of a time working with PHP and SOAP as well. I seem to recall a similar situation where I used the standard PHP class (new stdClass()) to help build the object with params. Here's the questions/answer page.

[How can I add Attributes to a PHP SoapVar Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211022/how-can-i-add-attributes-to-a-php-soapvar-object)

I hope it helps.

Comment: it certainly is a real pain to work with, I can't get my head around what you achieved in your other answer, do you have any more links that could help? Or even put your last answer into context of the above XML? Thank You

Comment: I used a stdClass() to construct the object with the parameters needed. My advice would be to var_dump data to try to understand what you've got and what you're missing.